# Visual studio code: navigate to jsx components

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code, I would like to be able to navigate to an imported file using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>.

[image]

So far I'm able to do it for javascript files (.js), but it's not working for react files (.jsx)

Here is what my directory structure looks like :

[image]

Here are the imports (relative and absolute) in my **TestImport.jsx** Component :

```
import DummyTwo from 'components/common/dummy-two/DummyTwo.jsx';
import something from 'components/common/my-file/myFile.js';

import DummyOne from '../common/dummy-one/DummyOne.jsx';
import somethingElse from '../common/my-file/myFile2.js';
```

And here is my **jsconfig.json** for vscode

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

**Code can be retrieved here:**
https://github.com/fthebaud/react-boilerplate

Am I missing something in the jsconfig file? regarding the extensions maybe?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add `"jsx": "react"` to use jsx:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) for more info about this setting

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for the info!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If my files have an extension that isn't *.js or *.jsx (ie: *.es), is there a way to get VSCode to recognize it within jsconfig.json?

The question's similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046039/vs-code-es6-extensions-cant-find-module

Comment: Thanks. Things became much easier because of this.

Comment: This goes in your `jscofig.json`? This also didn't do it for me. Does it work if the components are in another file?

Comment: For me  adding this worked "jsx": "react-jsx" in jsconfig.json